# Bounty for Accepted Answer?

Tags: discussion, support, bounty, accepted-answer

I posted a question about [*traveler wires*](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/292250/what-is-a-traveler-wire-and-how-does-it-work/292252#292252) and received an excellent answer.

I wanted to create/award a bounty as I believe it deserves it. I already accepted the answer and now do not see an option to create a bounty, would I need to *reverse* the acceptance of the answer to make a bounty?

Comment: Thank you! The extra points of a bounty at this time don't mean so much (though they still mean *something*). Simply telling me, as you did here, that the answer is that good is all the thanks I need!

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Understood, I am still curious about the process and intend to award a bounty. The answer definitely deserves it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question hasn't been opened long enough. Once it has been opened for 48 hours, the option should be available. See the [bounty FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/163027) has more details.